# if block being performed even when comparison values of Int are not equal (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, if-statement

```
func audioControllerDidFinishLoadingAudioForKey(key: Int) {

    print("current line position")
    print(scriptTableView.currentLinePosition)
    print("key")
    print(key)

    if scriptTableView.currentLinePosition == key && pausedPlayback == false {

        playbackRecordingWithKey(key)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            if self.recordLines == true {
                self.setToolbarState(.RecordMode)
            } else {
                self.setToolbarState(.Playing)
            }

        })
    }
}
```

I am having some very strange behaviour with this if-statement.

The above function always performs the if block, even if the key is a different value to the currentLinePosition (both are Ints). The print output shows for example:

```
current line position
25
key
27
playbackRecordingWithKey
```

But "playbackRecordingWithKey" is still being called (there is a print function there as well)

Does anybody know why this might be happening or how to debug this? I'm a bit stumped here.

Comment: Could it be the case that the value of currentLinePosition is changed by another thread between the print and the comparison?

Comment: Is 'playbackRecordingWithKey' being called from this if-statement, or could it be getting called from elsewhere?

If you step through this code does it go where you're expecting?

Comment: I just came here back to edit my post, yes you are absolutely right and thank you for answering so quickly! I put the code that called this function onto the main thread and that fixed the problem.

Comment: @russell no thats the only function that calls playbackRecordingWithKey, thank you though!

Comment: Please do not include answers in questions. You can always post your own answer to your question if you want, or ask the commenter to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Noted, I'll change it now. Cheers for the heads up! @EricD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @HugoTunius for suggesting multithreading as the problem and to everyone else for their input.

Turns out that putting the code that called 'audioControllerDidFinishLoadingAudioForKey' onto the main thread fixed my problem. I don't think that the currentLinePosition value changed between the print functions and the if statement because of two things:

- When testing the problem I made sure that the line position was never the same value as the key.
- The amount of time taken before the function is called varies (due to differing data sizes) so having line position change at that exact time every time seems very unlikely to me.

Maybe the value of currentLinePosition (where it == key) was captured when the thread was created or something, I really don't know. Interesting though that despite the line position value in the function being equal to key, print() showed the main thread value. If I find something that is important to do with multithreading related to this problem I will comment below.